# Index was out of range... Why I got this error? I don't use that

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, indexing

I got error...  System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

================================================

```
Exception Desc >> Time[20180721_04:44:07] Message[Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection 매개 변수 이름: index] Source[mscorlib]StackTrace[   위치: System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   위치: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)]
```

================================================

why I got this error??? 
I don't use System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(int32 Index)

this is a part of my source code that error point

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel base_MessageBar;
...
public void MyFunctionAtErrorPoint(String str)
{
    if (base_MessageBar.ForeColor != Color.Black) base_MessageBar.ForeColor= Color.Black;
    this.base_MessageBar.Text = str;
}
```

- Environmentally, I can not debug. ***
- It is occured 1/1000000 % percently ***
- If it is occured, window's ToolStripLabel draw a "Red X" ***

Comment: "It is occured 1/1000000 % percently ***" of what? its not a progress bar, it seems to be a text bar.  Please produce the [minimal, viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of this in action

Comment: Possibly changing stuff on a background thread that needs to be changed on the UI thread.

Comment: Do you even use an  ArrayList? Any Paint events coded? Do you dynmically modify the menues? - Maybe you need to clean the solution..

Comment: @BugFinder I'm So Sorry.. I don't English well.. 0.0000001 Percent...
==> error is very very sometimes occured...

Comment: @MineR I think your idea is right... But How correct this error...
Can I Lock??

Comment: @TaW I don't ArrayList.. I don't call any paint function... just I set str to base_MessageBar.Text ...

Comment: @sangho you need to produce a workable small example where we can see this occurr

Comment: I'm so sorry.. I don't English well.. and I'm not senior in C# programming...
I'm really sorry to have troubled you.

Comment: Never change any Winforms element from a background thread, except in an Invoke.

Comment: fianlly.. just only one.. If I use U.I draw thread (like invoke).. can I solve this error?

Comment: @MineR Oh !! Thanks .. very very Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I sovled this error by using a Invoke Function

I was set some U.I values in non U.I thread ...

I hope this writing is helpful to someone ...